# On First Click, Original Page Coming. But, On Second Click, 'Page Not Found' Error Coming. - Yii2-App-Basic

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I got one awkward issue.

My **views/layout/main.php** is:

```
echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
                Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                ['label' => 'Register', 'url' =>['users/users/register']]:
                ['label' => 'D',''=>''],

                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['users/users/index']],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['users/users/about']],
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>
```

Whenever I'm clicking On Home Tab, Page is opening. Its Ok.

```
http://localhost/mylawsuit/yii/web/index.php?r=users/users/index
```

[image]

Again Clicking on Home Tab, Page giving error Like

Page Not Found.

```
http://localhost/mylawsuit/yii/web/index.php?r=users/users/users/index
```

[image]

In Url, one more "users" getting appendend in middle. That's why Page Not Found Coming. Users is one module.

Again, clicking On Home Tab, Page is coming without error. Means Original Page Coming.

For me, i've to click 2 times each on every tab to get original page.
First time, error. Second Time, Original Page.

But, I solved it by changing `'url' => ['users/users/index']]` of **main.php** to `'url' => ['/users/users/index']],` 
means adding one forward slash to URL. It's working fine.

What may be the issue. Or Writing like this `'url' => ['/users/users/index']]` is the main syntax. Forgive me, If this is the syntax to write the URL.

Comment: Thats just the difference between a relative and an absolute url

Comment: apply pretty url and then reproduce error

Comment: you can also use `Url::to(['path/to/route'])` as `url` in `NavBar`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use absolute url with / on begining like:

```
'url' => ['/users/users/index']
```

without / Yii creates a relative url which is relative to current page, absolute url is always the same on every page.